# Using ajax to display what is being typed not working, PHP, AJAX, JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Using ajax, I'm trying to display what is being typed in the text box, but it's not displaying anything at all for some reason. I know the ajax function itself got called, by using alert inside the function, and I think the real problem is actually in test2.php, but I'm not sure what I did wrong. Please take a look:

> test1.php

```
<?php

include('ajax.php');

echo "<input type = 'text' name = 'select' onkeyup = 'ajax(\"test2.php\",\"select\",\"output\")'>";
echo "<div id = 'output'/>";

?>
```

> test2

```
<?php

$select = $_POST['select'];
echo $select;

?>
```

> ajax.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function ajax(url,select,id) {

      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: { select: $('select[name="select"]').val()},
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
             document.getElementById( id ).innerHTML = data;
           }

      });

}

</script>
```

Comment: select[name="select"] is invalid. Shouldn't it be `"input[name='select']"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function ajax(url,unused,id) {
    $.post(url,{select: $('input[name="select"]').val()})
    .error(function(e){
        alert(e);
    })
    .success(function(d){
        $("#"+id).text(d);
    });
}
```

Comment: @ksealey Anyway for me to pass in the name in the parameter?

Comment: @frosty The name of the input field?

Comment: @ksealey Actually that's resolved. But I have a recent question open, if you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905603/passing-php-variables-through-the-parameters-to-a-javascript-function-php-java

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
 data: {select: $('select[name="select"]').val()},
```

There is no select element. And if you meant to get the id named element, then you need to change it to:

```
data: {select: $('#select[name="select"]').val()},
```

or in your case:

```
data: {select: $('input[name="select"]').val()},
```