# Passing php variables through the parameters to a javascript function, PHP, JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to pass a string variable through the parameter of a php function called alertText to a javascript function called alert, to alert a message to the screen, but it's not accepting the php variable for some reason, and nothing is being alerted to the screen. Please take a look:

> testing.php

```
function alertText($text) {

echo "

<script>
alert($text);
</script>

";

}

alertText("Hello");

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to single-quote the $text variable, because JavaScript is not recognizing that variable as string.

```
<?php 
function alertText($text) {
    echo "<script>alert('$text');</script>";
}
alertText("Hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could concatenate it to get a more readable code.

```
function alertText($text) {
    echo "<script>alert('".$text."');</script>";
}

alertText('Hello');
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple mistake, you forgot to close the double quote letting the parser know that $text is not the word $text (hey it could happen!).

We use .$variable_name. to concatenate the value of the variable with the javascript function at runtime.

```
   <?php

   function alertText($text) {

    echo "
       <script>
         alert('".$text."');
       </script>
    ";

    }

    alertText("Hello");

    ?>
```

** EXAMPLE CORRECTED **

Answer (score 1):

You should use it like

```
    function alertText($text) {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $text . '"); </script>';

";

}

alertText("Hello");

?>
```